# export Intellij project including libraries to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I have an intellij project which is using log4j and junit libraries (in my external libraries section). I need to export the project to Eclipse project including the libraries. The intellij option for exporting to eclipse is just generating the .project and .classpath files and nothing else. How would I export that project so that it will contain all dependencies and someone using eclipse would be able to compile and run the program without additional work?
Also this is a normal java project (not maven)

Comment: The simplest thing is to just use maven. With two libraries its a trivial POM and any sane IDE can import it and pick up the dependencies.

Comment: yes, this is what I ended up doing, but I thought it is worth asking if there is another way..

Comment: I'm sure you can get it to work, in theory the .project/.classpath stuff point to the in-project libs (assuming you've put them there), then you can just archive the whole thing up. But it just isn't worth the fiddling and the hassle when pom-based project imports tend to just work.